# kafka fetch records by timestamp, consumer loop

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka 0.10.2.1 cluster. I am using the Kafka's offsetForTimes API to seek to a particular offset and would like to breakout of the loop when i have reached the end timestamp.

My code is like this:

```
//package kafka.ex.test;

import java.util.*;



import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndTimestamp;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;

public class ConsumerGroup {


   public static OffsetAndTimestamp fetchOffsetByTime( KafkaConsumer<Long, String> consumer , TopicPartition partition , long startTime){

      Map<TopicPartition, Long> query = new HashMap<>();
      query.put(
              partition,
              startTime);

      final Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetResult = consumer.offsetsForTimes(query);
      if( offsetResult == null || offsetResult.isEmpty() ) {
         System.out.println(" No Offset to Fetch ");
         System.out.println(" Offset Size "+offsetResult.size());



         return null;
      }
      final OffsetAndTimestamp offsetTimestamp = offsetResult.get(partition);
      if(offsetTimestamp == null ){
         System.out.println("No Offset Found for partition : "+partition.partition());
      }
      return offsetTimestamp;
   }

   public static KafkaConsumer<Long, String>  assignOffsetToConsumer( KafkaConsumer<Long, String> consumer, String topic , long startTime ){
      final List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfoList = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);
      System.out.println("Number of Partitions : "+partitionInfoList.size());
      final List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = new ArrayList<>();
      for (PartitionInfo pInfo : partitionInfoList) {
         TopicPartition partition = new TopicPartition(topic, pInfo.partition());
         topicPartitions.add(partition);
      }
      consumer.assign(topicPartitions);
      for(TopicPartition partition : topicPartitions ){
         OffsetAndTimestamp offSetTs = fetchOffsetByTime(consumer, partition, startTime);


         if( offSetTs == null ){
            System.out.println("No Offset Found for partition : " + partition.partition());
            consumer.seekToEnd(Arrays.asList(partition));
         }else {
            System.out.println(" Offset Found for partition : " +offSetTs.offset()+" " +partition.partition());
            System.out.println("FETCH offset success"+
                    " Offset " + offSetTs.offset() +
                    " offSetTs " + offSetTs);
            consumer.seek(partition, offSetTs.offset());
         }
      }
      return consumer;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


      String topic = args[0].toString();
      String group = args[1].toString();

      long start_time_Stamp =  Long.parseLong( args[3].toString());
      String bootstrapServers = args[2].toString();
      long end_time_Stamp =  Long.parseLong( args[4].toString());
      Properties props = new Properties();
      boolean reachedEnd = false;

      props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
      props.put("group.id", group);
      props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
      props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
      props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
      props.put("key.deserializer",
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
      props.put("value.deserializer",
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

      KafkaConsumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<Long, String>(props);
      assignOffsetToConsumer(consumer, topic, start_time_Stamp);


      System.out.println("Subscribed to topic " + topic);
      int i = 0;

      int arr[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
      while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<Long, String> records = consumer.poll(6000);
         int count= 0;
         long lasttimestamp = 0;
         long lastOffset = 0;
            for (ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record : records) {

               count++;

               if(arr[record.partition()] == 0){
                  arr[record.partition()] =1;
               }


               if (record.timestamp() >= end_time_Stamp) {
                  reachedEnd = true;
                  break;
               }


               System.out.println("record=>"+" offset="
                       +record.offset()
                       + " timestamp="+record.timestamp()
                        + " :"+record);
               System.out.println("recordcount = "+count+" bitmap"+Arrays.toString(arr));

            }

         if (reachedEnd) break;
         if (records == null || records.isEmpty()) break; // dont wait for records
      }

   }



}
```

I face the following problems:

1. consumer.poll fails even for 1000 millisecond. I had to poll a few times in loop if i use 1000 millisecond. I have an extremely large value now. But having already, seeked to the relevant offsets within a partition, how to reliably set the poll timeout so that data is returned immediately?
2. My  observations is that when data is returned it is not always from all partitions. Even when data is returned from all partitions not all records are returned. The amount of records that are in the topic is more than 1000. But the amount of records that are actually fetched and  printed in loop is less(~200). Is there any issue with the current usage of my Kafka APIs?

how to reliably break out of the loop having obtained all the data between start and end timestamp and not prematurely?

Answer (score 2):

1. Amount of records fetched per poll depends on your consumer config
2. You are breaking the loop when one of the partitions reaches the endtimestamp , which is not what you want . You should check that all the partitions are seeked to end before exiting poll loop
3. Poll call is an async call and fetch requests and responses are per node , so you may or may not get all the responses in a poll depending on the broker response time